# Duplicate class contained in the libs of android project

Tags: android

When I was trying to use Android Studio to debug my project, I got the following error,

**Class `com.google.ads.AdRequest.Gender` has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.**

The cause seems to be that the google play services lib and another lib used by my project both contain the `com.google.ads.AdRequest.Gender` class, and **I don't think I can remove it from either one.**

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks a lot.

I tried the following statement in build.gradle in order to exclude the duplicated classes in the google play services lib, but it still does not solve the problem.

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.ads'
}
```

Comment: What projects do you have in dependency to your project?

Comment: com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32 and another one called DatawindAdsSdk-2.0, and both of them contain the com.google.ads.AdRequest.Gender class.

Comment: Try read this http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2010/02/java-duplicate-class-and-mismatched.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Gradle's `exclude` mechanism when setting up the DatawindAdsSdk-2.0 dependency. There are [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html) available, but it will probably look something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/datawindAdsSdk-2.0.jar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.ads'
    }
}
```

experiment with that and see if you can get it working.

Comment: I tried that 

compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.ads'
}

and it still gives the same error

Comment: You may have to experiment and see if something in that form will work for you. If you work at it and you're still stuck, add your build.gradle file and the full output from the compile to your question.

Answer (score 0):

But I came to this post via google and I read this post has the same problem as me. I solved it excluding the group and the whole library. In my case the problem was with an animatorListener.

```
compile ('com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.8.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
}
```

This is my post [duplicate library gradle animatorlistener duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297249/duplicate-library-gradle-animatorlistener-duplicate/28298042?noredirect=1#comment44948666_28298042)