# How to resolve two different classes with the same name in dependencies

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-cloud-platform, dependencies

I will say right away that I have not found the answer to the question below anywhere.

In `build.gradle(:app)` I have:

```
...
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
...
```

After adding:

```
implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:26.1.1')
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-kms'
```

During **Rebuilding Project** I got an error message specifically:

> Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules
> jetified-proto-google-common-protos-2.9.2
> (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.9.2) and
> jetified-protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime
> (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)

I found this class `com.google.api.Advice` and it turned out that they are two completely different classes with the same `package`:

**Gradle: com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0@aar**

```
package com.google.api;

import ...

public final class Advice extends GeneratedMessageLite<Advice, Advice.Builder> 
    implements AdviceOrBuilder {
    ...
}
```

**Gradle: com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.9.2**

```
package com.google.api;
        
public final class Advice extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3
                implements AdviceOrBuilder {
    ...
}
```

Because of this, I can't just `exclude` any of these classes. And even more so after the exclusion of any of these classes, I have a partial loss of functionality of my application.

As a result, I have to leave these classes. But how to do that?
Or maybe I've localized the problem incorrectly?

Comment: Maybe this topic can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319020/duplicate-class-contained-in-the-libs-of-android-project

Comment: @mazlum I looked at the link, but the `exclude` command is used there. This doesn't solve my problem. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I've the same issue, could you please share with us your solution if possible